Where can i get the pseudo Range Correction (PRC) from RTCM messages? GPS
how’s it going?
I'm trying to correct the position of a GNSS receiver that outputs NMEA data, so I need to do some post-processing on a PC.
I saw the algorithm DGNSS-CP that needs ephemeris info to calc the satellite position (which I get from a CORS network) and something called "correction data" (which are PRC corrections for each satellite). Im getting RTCM 3 messages from a CORS but i just dont know if the PRC correction is supossed to be an attibute or if the RTCM 3 message (type 1004) contains all the neccessary data to calculate the PRC, so my question is: where do i get the PRC?
I think the PRC info I'm looking for is in these RTCM messages (I believe it’s message type 1004), am I on the right track?
edit: i saw that is easier to get in RTCM v2, is this correct?
